# plim$(g(X_n\cdot Y_n)) = g(X\cdot Y)$ where plim$(X_n)=X$, plim$(Y_n) =Y$? Is this just the continuous mapping theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> $\operatorname{plim}(X_n\cdot Y_n) = X\cdot Y$ where $\operatorname{plim}(X_n)=X$, $\operatorname{plim}(Y_n) =Y$.

Why is this correct? (Here $\operatorname{plim}$ stands for the convergence in probability.)

I believe this is just a simple application of the continuous mapping theorem:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{plim}
\plim(Z_n)=Z\implies  \plim g(Z_n) = g(Z)\tag{1}
$$
and that it thus holds for a general function $g$ instead of just multiplication (and addition, and division)

However, the [Wikipedia page for the continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Statement) states that the set of point where $g$ is discontinuous has measure zero *with respect to $Z$* (using the notation in (1))

So then for $\plim(g(X_n\cdot Y_n)) = g(X\cdot Y)$ to be true is the requirement that the probability of $X\cdot Y$ being in the set of discontinuous points of $g$ be zero? If so, how do we know that $X\cdot Y$ is indeed the $\plim$ of $X_n\cdot Y_n$, since we need the CMT for this?

More generally, I am wondering how we is the continuous mapping theorem applied to a function of *multiple* random variables. This is not clear to me.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand the whole $g(X_n\cdot Y_n)$ thing, but try to apply CMT to the (convergent in probability) *vector* sequence $(X_n,Y_n)$ and the function $g(x,y) = xy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by zhoraster helped me figure it out.

Since we know each Random Variable converges in probability to something, and convergence is probability for a random **vector** is defined as element wise convergence, we know that the random vector $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in probability to $(X,Y)$.

Then, to get the result, we simply apply the CMT to* the random **vector** $(X_n,Y_n)$.

To state where I was confused: I was thinking about applying a continuous function to $X_n, Y_N$ as applying the CMT to two random variables, and I did not see how the proof applied to two random variables. What we actually do is apply the CMT to a random vector $(X_n,Y_n)$ whose convergence in probability follows from the definition of convergence in probability for a random vector (or matrix)

*Technical aside: technically we apply the CMT to to the sequence of random vectors, since convergence deals with sequences.